# FLUTTER and FIREBASE: How to increment an int in a map?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I use flutter + firebase and I have a problem, in my db I have a 'Votes' value that is an array of 2 int. I want to increment them using like this : 'Votes': [FieldValue.increment(nb1), FieldValue.increment(nb2)], but it is not working, so I'm stuck I don't know how to increment them.

```
  Future vote(String voteid) async {
    List<dynamic> listvote = [];
    List<dynamic> vote1 = [];
    List<dynamic> vote2 = [];
    List<dynamic> votevierge = [];
    var vote = nomines.indexOf(voteid);
    int nb1 = 0;
    int nb2 = 0;

    final snapShot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('rooms').document(pincode).get();
    if (snapShot != null) {
      listvote = snapShot.data['Votes'];
      vote1 = snapShot.data['Vote1'];
      vote2 = snapShot.data['Vote2'];
      listvote[vote] = listvote[vote] + 1;
      if (vote == 0) {
        votevierge = List.from(vote1);
        votevierge.add(nameid);
        nb1 = 1;
      } else {
        votevierge = List.from(vote2);
        votevierge.add(nameid);
        nb2 = 1;
      }
      vote++;
      Firestore.instance.collection('rooms').document(pincode).updateData({
        'Votes': [FieldValue.increment(nb1), FieldValue.increment(nb2)],
        'Vote$vote': votevierge,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: That syntax just won't work. Firestore doesn't let you directly address array elements in an update.  You will have to read the document, update the array elements in memory, and write the document back. Arrays are often not very helpful because of this constraint.

Comment: have you found a solution to this? if yes, then please let me know i am facing the same difficulty right now.

Comment: @basudevnayak  I found a solution. Please have a look in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the value of a field by .set() method with Setoptions().

For example, i have a map of question in the firebaseFirestore and i want to increment the value of 'upVotes' key by 1 then :

[image].

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('questions').doc(questionId).set({

 'question' : {
 'upVotes' : FieldValue.increment(1),
 },
 // This option helps in merging with initial  data

 SetOptions(merge:true),

 });
```